# Question 3 of the 2018 International Mathematic Olympiad

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

A neighbour who recently finished high school is showing interest in mathematics and she asked me to solve the Question 3 of the 2018 International Mathematics Olympiad. I found 3 solutions (before a suggestion provided in a comment below) and reviewed all of them but, in my opinion, those solutions skip steps so that even people who did lots of maths (let's say in engineering) do not understand them, not to mention that my maths lecturers would not give full marks to those solutions because many expressions are not demonstrated.
Some people on these forums accept solutions with missing bits and pieces which contribute to many young people losing interest or even feeling scared of mathematics. At a minimum, the solutions should include a sentence such as "The proofs of equations or inequations (1), (2), ..., (n) are left for you", otherwise some young people feel that the solution is complete but they are too stupid for mathematics.
About my progress: I understand and proved everything until line 8. In line 9, first sentence, I have difficulties with proving the word "distinct". Also in line 9, I have difficulties proving the inequality which works for n=4 (10 <= 1+2+3+4) but if you look at the figure in the question, it does not work for neither n=3 (7 > 1+2+3) nor n=2 (6 > 1+2). Could someone please write a step-by step-solution for those two issues?
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2018_IMO_Problems/Problem_3

Comment: There's also a discussion on AoPS. Have you seen it?

Comment: The solution looks complete to me, in the sense that if this was submitted at IMO, it would score a full 7. If you're having trouble understand it, I recommend you to 1) Write up your own version of it, 2) List out the specific parts that you're having through with, 3) Express why you're having trouble with those parts and why it can't be "fixed".

Comment: Adola: I found a discussion here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1670582p10626557  Thanks.

Comment: Calvin Lin: In line 6 of the solution as posted in the link I provided, the sum goes from k=i+1 to k=j but the variable is m-sub-i, not m-sub-k. I now realize that has to be a typo (which means such solution should not score a full 7). Also, the inequalities in lines 6 and 8 should be proved, not simply written. I just proved them. I studied engineering and did lots of maths and in maths assessments we were marked down for anything that was not obvious. But if you say that for people who studied pure mathematics those inequalities are extremely obvious I will have to accept that.